# Common function to create Sessions for DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

I am developing an AWS Lambda based application which uses go SDK.

I have multiple functions which make calls to DynamoDB APIs.

Currently in each every function I am creating the session.

Instead of this I am thinking, if I can create a common method which can create a session. This session can be used by other functions.

The code snippet is as below -

```
func GetDynamoDbConnection(customerId string) *dynamodb.DynamoDB {

    roleArn := constants.IAM_ROLE_ARN_PREFIX + constants.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID + ":" + constants.IAM_ROLE_STR + constants.IAM_CUST_ROLE_PREFIX + "-" + customerId
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())
    creds := stscreds.NewCredentials(sess, roleArn)
    dynamoDbSession := dynamodb.New(sess, &aws.Config{Credentials: creds})

    return dynamoDbSession

}
```

I call this function as below -

```
dbInfo := utils.GetDynamoDbConnection(customerId)
```

But when I use this session to make DynamoDb calls, it doesn't work. 
I get an error - Access Denied.

But if I create the session in the same function where I am using it, it works.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to be fine. Do make sure that the function calls inside the *GetDynamoDbConnection* are getting the apt parameters and returning the expected data.

Here, the error *Access Denied* probably hints that the *Role ARN* might not be correctly configured in the *stscreds.NewCredentials* function. So, check if the *RoleARN* string has the appropriate value.

Comment: I corrected the Role ARN and it started working fine. Thanks @supreet